# How can the following errors be corrected?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for some time for the cause of these errors. Does anyone see what's wrong here? Thank you very much.

The following two messages appear in the console:

> ReferenceError: exampleCode is not defined

and

> TypeError: exampleCode.getValue0 is not a function

```js
//exampleCode.js

(function(exampleCode) {
  "use strict";

  var value0 = yawnFactor;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (value0 >= 1) {
      value0 = 0;

    } else {

      value0 += 0.00;
    }
  });

  Object.assign(exampleCode, {
    getValue0: function() {
      return value0;
    }
  });

})(window.exampleCode = window.exampleCode || {});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//var exampleCode = {}

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("./three/models/model.json", function(geometry, materials) {
  var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./three/models/model.jpg');
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    skinning: true,
    transparent: true,
    map: texture
  });

  var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.scale.set(2.9, 1.9, 2.5);
  mesh.position.set(0, -16, 0);
  mesh.rotation.set(0.0, 3.15, 0.0);
  scene.add(mesh);

  var helper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(mesh);
  helper.material.linewidth = 2;
  helper.visible = false;
  scene.add(helper);

  render();

  function update() { //<-- this giv the Errors, but it is running.
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    mesh.skeleton.bones[11].rotation.z = exampleCode.getValue0();
  }
  update();

});
```

Comment: yep, `exampleCode` is not defined

Comment: @Jaromanda X 7 thanks for answer. if I define exampleCode (var exampleCode; the message 'TypeError: exampleCode.getValue0 is not a function' is still displayed. What is the reason ?

Comment: because `var exampleCode` means `exampleCode === undefined` - and `undefined` does not have a property called `getValue0`

Comment: understand, now I noticed that the code was not complete "see update". Should not that be defined? I still have the errors :-(

Comment: `Object.assign( exampleCode` ...  `exampleCode` needs to be an `Object` ... so, before this, `var exampleCode={}` would be one fix

Comment: the ReferenceError is gone, I still have the TypeError. I only wrote var exampleCode = {}

Comment: @Jaromanda X 7 thank you for your efforts. I have adapted the following. The  "TypeError: exampleCode.getValue0 is not a function"  I still have.

Answer (score 0):

*exampleCode.js* defines `window.exampleCode` as an empty object, then assigns a `getValue0` method on it.

At this point you can call `exampleCode.getValue0();`.

After that you say `var exampleCode = {}` which **overwrites** that object with a new **empty** object.

`exampleCode.getValue0` no longer exists.

Then you try to call `exampleCode.getValue0();`, which doesn't exist any more, so you get an error.

Don't overwrite `exampleCode`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. However, I get the errors even if I omit var exampleCode = {} . The question is why?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qihuvowune/1/edit?js,console — I get `ReferenceError: yawnFactor is not defined`, which isn't the error you quoted. Try providing a real [mcve].

Comment: yawnFactor coms from a facedetection tool and can not by defined on your example. They are calculations of individual coordinates. the mistake will have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Tom — Finding your mistake when your code makes other errors is hard. That is why you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: ok, sorry for the incompleteness. I will try to give more complete information. I will rethink this one tonight. Many thanks for your help.